# Como chamar ActionResult de outra Area com um link html?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Olá, tenho um link em uma `View` e preciso direcionar este link para uma `ActionResult` que fica em outra `Area` do meu projeto.

É um link de `Sair` para chamar o a `ActionResult Logoff`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Texto do Link", "Acao", new { area = "Tal", controller = "ControllerDaAreaTal" } )
```

Comment: Perfeito. Funcionou de cara.